# textwrap module not available in Python3.11 or Pycharm

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, openai-api

I am using Pycharm to develop a Python script that uses OpenAI API that needs the `textwrap` module, however the module is not available in the packages and either on the Python3.11 site-packages on my Mac.
Has this module been retired or has it been upgraded to a different module?

Comment: Have you tried to install using ```pip install -U textwrap3```?

Comment: `textwrap` is a built-in module. how did you install python on this machine?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me using the Python3 that ships with macOS:

```
> /usr/bin/python3
Python 3.8.9 (default, Oct 26 2021, 07:25:54) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import textwrap
>>>
```

And even on a newer macOS release the Python version is 3.9.6. So I have no idea why you mention "python3.11". But that does happen to be the version I have installed via Homebrew and it also has a textwrap module. So, no, the textwrap module has not been retired or replaced by a different module.